# Maximum index of a generalized eigenvector of $A$ associated to $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

My textbook says the following:

> Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$. Then max-ind($λ$), the maximum
>   index of a generalized eigenvector of $A$ associated to $\lambda$, is the
>   largest value of $j$ such that $A$ has a generalized eigenvector of index
>   $j$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

However, the index of the generalized eigenvector $v$ is *defined* as the **smallest** $j$ with $(A − \lambda I)^j(v)=0$.

Is it just me or does the definition contradict itself with regard to "largest/smallest" value of $j$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an easy example, like $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Consider $\lambda =1$.    It has ordinary eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and generalized eigenvectors of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a\\1\end{pmatrix}$  (easy to see).

The index of $ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ is the min over all $n$ such that $(A-1I)^n\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}=0$.  So it's $1$.

For $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, say, $(A-1I) \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.  So the index is $2$.

Finally since the $\operatorname{max-ind}(1)$ of $\lambda =1$ is defined to be the max of these two indices, it is $2$.